# Pick a specific folder in a Path and the name of a file to set 2 differents variables

Tags: batch-file, substring, directory

Sorry to ask a question which will be an easy one for many of you I guess...

I'm a student in a CG School, but for the need of my project I need to code a simple `.bat` file to run on many computers. Everything works pretty fine, but now I need to simplify it to gain extra time setting up the `.bat`.

We have ALWAYS a Path like that :

```
D:\Project\Production\Shot\Render\Room\maya\scenes\Room_01.mb
```

I need two variables which store :

```
project : D:\Project\Production\Shot\Render\Room\maya
scene : Room_01
```

I think I need a loop which analyzes the path backward and sets the path after seeing 2 `\` in order to avoid the file name, and the `scenes` folder. And I need an other thing to store all the file name `######.mb` removing the `.mb`

I tried many things with substring forum, but it's kinda black magic for me...
So if anyone could help, I would be so grateful to you ! :)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to use a `for` command. It will allow you to retrieve different properties of a file system reference.

```dos
set "fileReference=D:\Project\Production\Shot\Render\Room\maya\scenes\Room_01.mb"

for %%a in ("%fileReference%") do set "scene=%%~na"
```

Where `%%~na` is the name of the element being referenced by the `for` replaceable parameter `%%a`

```dos
for %%a in ("%fileReference%\..\..") do set "project=%%~fa"
```

Where `%%~fa` is the full path of the element being referenced by the `for` replaceable parameter `%%a`

Comment: Thank you SO much ! It works wonderfully ! You can't imagine how many time we will save thanks to you. 
Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop is typically needed here. The first for loop grabs the last element of the string when split by a backslash. The path is then modified to have the file name removed from it, and then another for loop grabs the end off that string in the same manner.

```dos
@echo off
set my_path=D:\Project\Production\Shot\Render\Room\maya\scenes\Room_01.mb

for %%F in ("%my_path%") do set file=%%~nxF

echo.%file%

call set modded_path=%%my_path:\%file%=%%

for %%F in ("%modded_path%") do set folder=%%~nxF

echo.%folder%
```